# Non-random parameter estimation, alternative terminology?

Tags: estimation, references, terminology

I have a book [Navigation Signal Processing for GNSS [*sic*, global navigation satellite system] Software Receivers](http://www.sae.org/images/books/toc_pdfs/BART029.pdf)" by Thomas Pany (2010) that describes **non-random parameter estimation** as a fundamental method used by GPS receivers for non-linear tracking.

However, two other books I have "Estimation with Applications to Tracking and Navigation" by Bar-Shalom, and "Global Navigation Satellite Systems, Inertial Navigation, and Integration" by Grewal, make no mention of this method.

I suspect that the method has some alternative name or terminology so the other books are covering it, but I don't know what that is. Are there alternative ways of describing or implementing non-random parameter estimation that these other books might be using?

Comment: Can you tell us some thing about that method, some details?